# Access Jboss 7.1 EJB from Jboss 5.1 EJB

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

There is an EJB running in Jboss 7.1 which needs to be accessed from another EJB running over Jboss 5.1.

I have followed the instructions of several pages. I got the communication to the ejb in Jboss 7.1 from a plain java class using:

```
final Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");  
jndiProperties.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4448");  
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);  
//jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "client");  
//jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");  
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");  
           
final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);  
           
return (BeanRemoteInterface) context.lookup(LOOKUP_STRING);
```

I have changed the defect port 4447 to 4448 and deactivated the realm-security subsystem, so the user and pass are not necessary for now.

However when I try communicate from the ejb in jboss 5.1, it doesn’t work. I made the changes to the creation of the InitialContext, and after a lot of tests I got this error which I couldn't solve:

```
12:15:13,219 ERROR [STDERR] javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: remote://127.0.0.1:4448 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server remote://127.0.0.1:4448:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server remote://127.0.0.1:4448:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: remote://127.0.0.1:4448]]]</code></pre>
```

jboss 7.1 is running with `-b 0.0.0.0`, so that's not the problem.